# Google Website Optimizer Control Script and W3C

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer

When I use the w3c validator (http://validator.w3.org), I'm getting loads over errors which are in the Google Website Optimizer Control Script.

Is there an solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[No](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=64418), [sorry](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/websiteoptimizer/thread?tid=1104572325062cac&hl=en).

> The unbalanced  tag marks
>   the end of the original content for
>   that page section. It is compatible
>   with all browsers.
>
> It will cause a problem, however, if
>   your CMS doesn't accept unbalanced
>   tags. There is no current Website
>   Optimizer workaround for this
>   situation.

If this is a deal-breaker, I'd recommend trying a different A/B testing tool. I happen to really love [Optimizely](http://optimizely.com).